# Custom Apollo Fragment

Tags: swift, graphql, apollo

I have a `Fragment` for all the artwork that I will receive from the server

```
fragment ImageFragment on Image {
  s: fitInUrl(width: 50, height: 50)
  m: fitInUrl(width: 100, height: 100)
  l: fitInUrl(width: 200, height: 200)
  xl: fitInUrl(width: 400, height: 400)
}
```

I wanted those values to be multiplied by `UIScreen.main.scale`, as such I created the fragment manually. The problem is that now I get an error when running code-gen `Cannot find fragment "ImageFragment".`

Is there any way to make Apolo Code-Gen to skip this?

Comment: Your fragment should be in a GraphQL file or inside of a JS file within a `gql` tagged template literal. Codegen should then correctly pick up the fragment.

Comment: @Herku if I add it inside the GraphQL file when I generate it again it won't be overridden?